# How do I hide Bootstrap tab content?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, bootstrap-4

In my Ember application I have a Bootstrap nav with nav-pills, which each show different content in a tab-content.  None are active until clicked.  What I want is to make the currently active tab (and pill) deactivate if clicked again, hiding all content.

```html
<div class="col-sm-9 nav-pills">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a class="tab-toggle" data-toggle="pill" href="#special-instructions">Special Instructions</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab-toggle" data-toggle="pill" href="#job-details">Job Details</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab-toggle" data-toggle="pill" href="#alerts">Alerts</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab-toggle" data-toggle="pill" href="#toolbox">Toolbox Talk</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab-toggle" data-toggle="pill" href="#load-cell">Load Cell</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content job-info">
  <div id="special-instructions" class="tab-pane fade in">
    <div class="row spacer-mb-1"></div>
    Special Instructions
  </div>
  <div id="job-details" class="tab-pane fade in">
    <div class="row spacer-mb-1"></div>
    Job Details
  </div>
  <div id="alerts" class="tab-pane fade in">
    <div class="row spacer-mb-1"></div>
    Alerts
  </div>
  <div id="toolbox" class="tab-pane fade in">
    <div class="row spacer-mb-1"></div>
    Toolbox Talk
  </div>
  <div id="load-cell" class="tab-pane fade in">
    <div class="row spacer-mb-1"></div>
    Load Cell
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm new to Ember and not sure how to include jQuery in it.  I have only a template and a route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when you're using ember I *strongly recommend* you don't use the default bootstrap JS file! This does not really play well together with ember. However there is [`ember-bootstrap`](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/) which gives you a component based API for the bootstrap functionalities.

Oh, and `jQuery` is part of ember itself, however you can disable this for newer ember versions.

However a simple tab navigation as you have is *very* easy to do with ember itself. Especially if you use `ember-truth-helpers`!

You can use simple `if`s for your tabs:

```
<ul>
  <li role="button" onclick={{action 'activate' 'tab1'}}>Tab1</li>
  <li role="button" onclick={{action 'activate' 'tab2'}}>Tab2</li>
</ul>

{{#if (eq currentTab 'tab1')}}
  <div>
    Tab 1
  </div>
{{/if}}

{{#if (eq currentTab 'tab2')}}
  <div>
    Tab 2
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

And while I usually would do `onclick={{action (mut currentTab) 'tab1'}}` to activate `tab1`, here I've used an action.

This is because of your *special functionality*:

> What I want is to make the currently active tab (and pill) deactivate if clicked again, hiding all content.

This is now easy to implement in that actions:

```
activate(name) {
  if(this.currentTab === name) {
    this.set('currentTab', '');
  } else {
    this.set('currentTab', name);
  }
}
```

And [here is a twiddle implementing this solution](https://ember-twiddle.com/9fbfc74f69fbe7127fcb58d8eb3e62ff?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).

Comment: hi thanks for answer. FYI in your twiddle, tab2's inner text is typed as "tab1" as a typo :)